# Use wildcards when searching in HttpContext.Cache

Tags: c#, regex, sqlcachedependency

Is there a way to use wildcards or a regex to search and remove items from `HttpContext.Cache`?

I can have in my cache "item_1", "item_2",...,"item_n" and I want to remove from cache all values that are related to keys with the pattern "item_*". How to achieve that without checking if the item exists and then remove it?

Ex:

instead of:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("item_1")
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("item_2")
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("item_3")
```

I want something like:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("item_*")
```

Comment: post some input,expected output,attempts :)

Comment: You could possibly loop all the keys, and then do a check with `string.StartsWith()`, and remove the items that match the criteria.

Comment: @vks see my last edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop the items like this:

```
foreach(var key in HttpContext.Current.Cache)
{
    if (key.StartsWith("item_"))
    {
        // remove the corresponding item here.
    }
}
```

The basic sample, and needs some tweaking to match your implementation.

AFAIK you can't remove items based on wildcards, as you need the specific key. *(Please prove me wrong)*

Answer (score 0):

```
^HttpContext\.Current\.Cache\.Remove\("item_.*?"\)$
```

You can try this.Replace with `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/65